# Excel Issue (combining the content of one column when the customer is the same)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an issue which I suspect may be fairly easy to solve but I can't seem to find any previous questions about it.

```
Customer          Type              Product
Peter             Proactive         Car
Sven              Reactive          Wheels
Sven              Proactive         Wheels
Peter             Proactive         Wheels
```

What I would like is that when a customer appears twice, and when the type is the same. Like with "Peter", then the products would add together. The ideal result would look like: (notice that Sven's products does **not** combine because the type is different).

```
Customer          Type              Product
Peter             Proactive         Car
Sven              Reactive          Wheels
Sven              Proactive         Wheels
Peter             Proactive         Wheels & Car
```

Ideally I would like to do this without using VBA, does anyone have any solution for this?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Take a look at pivot tables. You can build the view that you want and It can group together that data for you. Other than that, you'd either have a complete mess of Formula all over the place or the answer would be VBA.

Comment: Pivot table wouldn't work in my situation. Let's say I wanted to try the "complete mess formula" haha, where would I start?

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data by Customer and then by Type using the facilities on the Data tab of the ribbon. You can then add a column to your sorted data. If the first row of sorted data is in, say cells `A2:C2` then insert the following formula into `D2`

`=IF(AND(A2=A1,B2=B1),D1&" & "&C2,C2)`

Copy formula in `D2` into remaining cells of column corresponding to your data. Your "cumulative" text will be in column D.

If you want to preserve the original row order of your data, first add an index column with 1,2,3,4,... effectively giving each row of your data a row number. Include this column in the sort, add the formulae as described above, then convert cells from formulae to values by using Copy/Paste Special Values. Finally sort the data on the index column to get back to original row ordering.

Answer (score 0):

OK, assuming that there are no further unstated constraints being imposed, here's a solution which requires a couple of helper columns.

[image]

Column D is simply an index and column E is the index number of the preceding row which matches the current row for Name and Product or 0 if there is no preceding matching row. The first row of the data list cannot have a preceding row, so columns E and F for this row are simply assigned as 0 and the Product value, respectively. Rows 2 onwards of the data list contain formulae in columns E and F which once entered for the second row of data, can simply be copied downwards as new data is added to the list.

Note that the formula in E3 is an array formula and is committed from the formula bar by pressing the Ctrl, Shift and Enter keys simutaneously.

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! Working perfectly. Thank you very much for engaging and helping me solve this.

Comment: Please tick the solution for correct answer. The "clever" bit of this is obviously column E. This uses two features: a mix of absolute and relative addressing in defining the ranges in the formulae; an array function. If you are not familiar with these features they are well worth spending some effort to lean. Absolute/relative addressing is very basic stuff, but array formulae are more advanced.